# Pandas groupby date - specific date periods

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I want to be able to group my data by user and then by specific date periods - to get counts and means and let them be created in new columns per date period.

My data looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"USER_ID": ["AA1", "AB1", "AA3", "CD3", "AB4", "AA1", "AA1", "AA3", "AB4", "AB4"],
"ACTIVITY_CATEGORY": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
"DATE": ['2018-09-19', '2018-09-13', '2018-09-06', '2018-09-18', '2018-09-15', '2018-09-19', '2018-09-16', '2018-09-06', '2018-09-04', '2018-09-04']})
```

So, I usually do it as follows:

```
df.groupby(['USER_ID',pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='W')])['ACTIVITY_CATEGORY'].count()
```

But what I want now is to be able to get it for a specific week. Essentially being able to get something more like:

[image]

I have read the documentation on different manners of grouping in Grouper - and offsets that can be used. Still can not find something like this.

There is a fairly cumbersome way of doing this using a for loop and by using timedelta and subtracting 7 days from latest day - but it is highly inefficient on a large dataset. Looking for a more pythonic way.

Comment: What are week1, wee2, week3 ... ? If I am not mistaken your input df only have 3 different weeks.

Comment: Hey Daniel, well, yes in this particular subset of users - there are no activities happening in week1, but in general there are users who have activities in week1 too - hence I need to have a column for it.

Comment: So what will be week1, week2, week3,, week 4?

Answer (score 1):

is this similar to what you are trying to achieve

```
df['DATE'] = 'WEEK ' + pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.day/7).apply(math.ceil).apply(str)
df.pivot_table(index=['USER_ID'],columns=['DATE'],aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

Out:

```
         ACTIVITY_CATEGORY
DATE    WEEK 1  WEEK 2  WEEK 3
USER_ID         
AA1     0.0     0.0     3.0
AA3     2.0     0.0     0.0
AB1     0.0     1.0     0.0
AB4     2.0     0.0     1.0
CD3     0.0     0.0     1.0
```

Comment: Very eloquently done, but this has the same issue as anky_91. It does not generalise for me to get to Week 5, 6, 7, etc. It groups together the activities within the bucket of Week 1 to Week 4 when I include data from previous months.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try this:

```
df_new=df.groupby(['USER_ID',pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='W')])['ACTIVITY_CATEGORY']\
.count().reset_index()
df_new['week_num']=(df_new.DATE.dt.day//7)+1
print(df_new.pivot_table(index='USER_ID',columns=['week_num']).fillna(0))

            ACTIVITY_CATEGORY          
week_num                 2    3    4
USER_ID                             
AA1                    0.0  1.0  2.0
AA3                    2.0  0.0  0.0
AB1                    0.0  1.0  0.0
AB4                    2.0  1.0  0.0
CD3                    0.0  0.0  1.0
```

If week 1 is present, it should automatically populate.

Comment: This does exactly as my expected output shows, however, the issue with this approach is that it does not work for more than 1 month. i.e. Week 5, Week 6, Week 7 ... Week N. Due to `f_new.DATE.dt.day//7` it clobbers together the data from previous months into the same set of Week 1 to Week 4. I should have been more specific in my problem statement.

Comment: @Ash so you want output based on the week numbers? Meaning whatever week of the year the date falls under, the output should have that?

Comment: Yes, e.g. in this example, if I had data from 2018-08, it should be in Week 5 - 8. and if I had data from 2018-07, it should be in Week 9 - 13, etc.